# Variable Types in Excel VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel, variable-types

I want to create a function that calculate cell in a determined range.

When I return the value of the calc to excel I get an #VALUE! error, which means
that the variable types are different.

I tried to use Cint(var) and get the same error.

Here is the code without Cint():

```
Function CalcTest(Interval As Range) As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    x = Interval.Offset(0, 0).Value
    y = Interval.Offset(1, 0).Value
    CalcTest = x + y
End Function
```

I already tried:

```
Function CalcTest(Intervalo As Range) As Integer
    CalcTest = Interval.Offset(0, 0).Value + Interval.Offset(1, 0).Value
End Function
```

And:

```
Function CalcTest(Interval As Range) As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    x = CInt(Interval.Offset(0, 0).Value)
    y = CInt(Interval.Offset(1, 0).Value)
    CalcTest = x + y
End Function
```

And Without declarating de function type:

```
Function CalcTest(Interval As Range)
    ...
    ...
End Function
```

And in Excel I call the function with some range:

```
=CalcText(A1:A2)
```

What Am I doing wrong?

#

The big picture:

[image]

What I need to do is create a cel in any place that counts de total values
of the $R col for every occurrency of a key value in $N col.

For every time I have "TH" in $N Col, I need do accumulate de $R col value of that
row in a cel.

Same for many others $N Values.

In this sample the value of the accumulated cel for TH in $N is 25.

Tks for the help!!!

Comment: Why do you need VBA for this?

Comment: Why not use a SUMIF statement in an Excel formula?

Comment: Exactly my thoughts :)

Comment: I don't know how to figure out this. The SUMIF statement will sum the "one line ocurrency" of some value (TH for example) in the range. But how can I do this in the entirely range and always adding the result to just one cel (accumulated cel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this way hard on yourself.

Put this into a cell in row 2 and drag it down:

```
=SUMIF(N$2:N2,"TH",R$2:R2)
```

Comment: Tks for the tip, but I know that! I just simplified the function to ask here! Look at the Siddharth's answer!

Tks for the help!!!

Comment: @EdgarBarcellosJunior please post code which actually shows your problem - the error you have in the actual code must be different then, because the error with your above code is what my answer (and Siddharth Rout's) address.

Comment: I edit my question with the big picture and a link to a screenshot. Please have a look and thanks for the help!

Comment: @EdgarBarcellosJunior I updated this answer. You don't need VBA at all.

Comment: That works! I had not understood the SUMIF statement! Thanks enderland and Siddharth Rout for the clarify and for your time! This solve my problem in this sheet, but I still have doubts about manipulating values of cels in a range when I refer to it with range.offset(row,col).value. Anyway I am glad! Really thanks!

Comment: @EdgarBarcellosJunior you can always see previous post history when you click on the "edited XX ago" link - see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19302600/revisions) :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Public Function CalcTest(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Variant
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    CalcTest = rng1.Value + rng2.Value

    Exit Function
Whoa:
    CalcTest = "Please check the Range Values"
End Function
```

In an Excel cell, put this formula `=CalcText(A1,A2)`

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. I just simplified the function to ask here. But what I really need to do is search for values in a big range like $A:$D, and do it a n number of times. 

So I will need to work with rang.Offset(x,y).Value instead of rang.Value like you did.

The real question is, how to manipulate integer or long data in a rang.Offset(x,y).value? 

Tks for the help!!!

Comment: In that case you do not need `.Offset()`. You need to loop through the range. See @enderland's answer :)

Comment: @EdgarBarcellosJunior I see you have re-redirect enderland to this post :p. Ok can you exactly explain what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to find the sum of all the numbers in a range of mixed Types?

Comment: I edit my question with the big picture and a link to a screenshot. Please have a look and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should not simplify your code to something that doesn't fairly represent your question. From your comments and Question.

```
Function CalcTest(Interval As Range) As Integer
    Dim x As Range
    CalcTest = 0
    For Each x In Interval
        If IsNumeric(x) Then
            CalcTest = CalcTest + x.Value
        End If
    Next x
End Function
```

This will make sure what you are adding up is actually a number.

But as is this will not work any different then the worksheet function:

```
=Sum(Range)
```

Simply converting the values to `Integer` won't work if what you are converting is not converatble. If you pass a Letter to the `CInt()` function it will just fail.

Comment: Tks for the advise. But I'm confused now. If a cel value in excel is an integer like '10', why I can't manipulate then in a VBA script using offset (in case of searching this cel in a range)?